# Reference another cursor in a WITH clause in PL/SQL code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a cursor in PL/SQL stored procedure that uses a WITH clause to reuse some "raw data" and apply logic.

```
CURSOR cursor_a IS
  WITH raw_data AS
   (SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM table_a)
  SELECT p1.a1, p1.a2, p1.a3 FROM raw_data p1 WHERE p1.a1 = some_logic
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p2.a1, p2.a2, p2.a3 FROM raw_data p2 WHERE p2.a1 = some_logic
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p3.a1, p3.a2, p3.a3 FROM raw_data p3 WHERE p3.a1 = some_logic
```

Is there a way to reference another curse for that sub query used in the `WITH`?  I'd like to create another cursor using the same `raw_data`, but don't want to have redundant logic, since that query is very complex.

Comment: Huh, I don't think so. But, if you could create a **view** using that CTE, then you could use the view in that stored procedure and base cursors on it.

Comment: Oh! Of course. A view. Wow, sometimes I over complicate things! Thanks!